Quantum key distribution and its use cases
I recent came into contact into bb84 and its really interesting stuff, however I'm confused at how effective or better it is than normal encryption. I understand they use random polarization of photons to create keys, however if the polarization of the photons end up representing classical bits then wouldn't that be the same as a key formed using other conventional cryptography methods? Is there something I'm missing and not understanding about qkd?


wouldn't that be the same as a key...

Yes, the key you end up with is the same as any other key. The protocol is not about key creation or making some fancy new type of key. The protocol is about key distribution.
The problem is: How do you get the key to separated parties in the first place?
Well, transfer the key via a secure channel of course... But if you have a secure channel why not just use that to transmit your messages?
The problem is: How do you establish a secure channel in the first place! Well, you need to distribute a key to both parties. Hence quantum key distribution.
This is what bb84 helps with. Of course, it is not a huge help in practice since you need a fancy-shmancy channel for sending qubits, which very few people have...

Thank you that clears everything up I had some questions, however while writing the question I realized why your right.

I actually do have one more question. Assuming in the future everyone is capable of creating their own key, then what are benefits of using quantum encrypted keys to classically encrypted keys?

Hi Snarz. Generally, the comments section should not be used to ask new questions. Can you write it up your single new question as a new question post with appropriate context? Also, you might have some better luck asking at the Quantum Computing stack exchange or the Cryptography stack exchange, rather than Physics.

I'm sorry, I didn't know thank you for letting me know.
